# How to git clone on Google Cloud Platform behind cooperate firewall?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, git-clone

Right now I am trying to git clone some python library on Google Cloud Platform Virtual machine(my user directory where my code and data are stored). However, directly git clone is not possible as my company blocks access to github from GCP.

My former colleague mentioned some work around which I don't recall precisely. What I can think of is to do these 2 steps

1. git clone to personal PC
2. upload the zip to GCP using GCP tool and convert it to git

any better approach?

Comment: Git clone to what? Google Cloud Repository? Edit your question with more details.

Comment: In what way is "git clone" not possible?  What happens when you try and clone a repo?  Where are you cloning from ... is it Github?   Do you have git installed?

Comment: So you mean to say it is an enterprise GitHub or Public Git Hub..

Comment: Just a side question: Why your company block the access to GitHub? Do  you not bet your job if you bypass this restriction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mention your VM is behind a corporate firewall. For security reasons your firewall does not allow you to do this. So you should not try to find a workaround to bypass these rules, because this may create a security bridge.